# The equation for ad valorem or value tax is given by (1 + τ ) p1x1 + p2x2 = m. Does this imply that higher the p1 higher the tax?

Tags: taxation, value, fiscal-policy

In other words, do luxury goods get taxed more while cheaper goods are taxed less in the case of value tax?
Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you!